# Манипулирование блоком HTML через jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой необходимостью: подгружается шаблонный HTML блок.

```
var addItemBlock = $('<span>').load("src/featureAddedStructure.html .featureAdded");
```

Блок имеет следующую структуру:

```
<div class="featureAdded fade in">
<button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="padding-right:3px">x</button>
<div style="background: " class="featureAddedImg"></div>    
<div class="featureAddedName">
<p>...</p>
</div> </div>
```

Мне необходимо до того как я вставлю этот блок  на страницу добавить значения хранящиеся в переменных param1 и param2. Не могу понять как это можно сделать до добавления этого блока на страницу.

Comment: подумайте, может вам нужные темплейты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помещать загруженный контент не сразу в целевой `span`, а посреднический скрытый контейнер. Методу `load` добавить третьим параметром коллбэк функцию - она вызовется сразу после того, как в скрытый контейнер вставится загруженный текст. В этой функции надо будет вытащить контент контейнера в переменную, и поиском/заменой вставить значения  param'ов вместо неких шаблонов-placeholder'ов. Сделать поиск-замену 'PARAMxVALUE` на ваше значение:

```
<input type="hidden" name="param1" value="PARAM1VALUE" />
<input type="hidden" name="param2" value="PARAM2VALUE" />
```

В вашем коде не вижу, куда именно предполагается вставлять значения param1 и param2. Второй вариант - вставлять значения манипуляцией jQuery.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку... все решилось Callback функцией. Забываю я про них.